# I need dhclient to flush IP address/routes when link goes down

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, network-interface, iproute

I am running one Ubuntu Server 14.04 with network configuration using `/etc/network/interfaces` and so `ifup`/`ifdown` scripts.

I realised that if I configure one interface in DHCP mode, then I unplug the cable from the interface and the IP address configured via DHCP is maintained until the DHCP lease expires. What I need is dhclient to flush addresses and routes configured via DHCP in the interface when the link goes down immediately.

How can I get dhclient to flush IP addresses and routes when the link status is DOWN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ifplugd`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ifplugd) to run a command when an Ethernet cable is plugged or unplugged. I'm not sure whether installing `ifplugd` is necessary — it's possible that there's a built-in way with udev and upstart — but I can't find it in the upstart documentation.

Since you're using ifupdown, call `ifdown` when the cable is unplugged. In `/etc/ifplugd/ifplugd.action`, write something like

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" = "eth0" ] && [ "$2" = "down" ]; then
  ifdown "$1"
fi
```

Comment: Great! You provided me the key point.